# How to move a single file with (.JPEG, .JPG, .jpeg, .jpg) extensions) and change the extension to .jpg with Linux bash

Tags: linux, bash, file-extension, file-rename

I have an inotify wait script that will move a file from one location to another whenever it detects that a file has been uploaded to the source directory.

The challenge I am facing is that i need to retain the basename of the file and convert the following extensions:  .JPEG, .JPG, .jpeg  to .jpg so that the file is renamed with the .jpg extension only.

Currently I have this:

```
TARGET="/target"
SRC="/source"
( while [ 1 ]
    do inotifywait  -m -r -e close_write --format %f -q \
        $SRC | while read F
            do mv "$SRC/$F" $TARGET
            done
    done ) &
```

So I need a way to split out and test for those non standard extensions and move the file with the correct extension. All files not having those 4 extensions just get moved as is.

Thanks!

Dave

Answer (score 3):

```
if [[ "$F" =~ .JPEG\|jpg\|jpeg\|jpg ]];then 
   echo mv $F ${F%.*}.jpg
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `extglob` option with some parameter expansion:

```
#! /bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
TARGET=/target
SRC=/source
( while : ; do
    inotifywait -m -r -r close_write --format %f -q \
        $SRC | while read F ; do
    basename=${F##*/}                               # Remove everything before /
    ext=${basename##*.}                             # Remove everything before .
    basename=${basename%.$ext}                      # Remove .$ext at the end
    if [[ $ext == @(JPG|JPEG|jpeg) ]] ; then        # Match any of the words
        ext=jpg
    fi
    echo mv "$F" "$TARGET/$basename.$ext"

        done
  done ) &
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this format. (Updated)

```
TARGET="/target"
SRC="/source"

(
    while :; do
        inotifywait  -m -r -e close_write --format %f -q "$SRC" | while IFS= read -r F; do
            case "$F" in
            *.jpg)
                echo mv "$SRC/$F" "$TARGET/"  ## Move as is.
                ;;
            *.[jJ][pP][eE][gG]|*.[jJ][pP][gG])
                echo mv "$SRC/$F" "$TARGET/${F%.*}.jpg"  ## Move with new proper extension.
                ;;
            esac
        done
    done
) &
```

Remove `echo` from the `mv` commands if you find it correct already. Also it's meant for `bash` but could also be compatible with other shells. If you get an error with the `read` command try to remove the `-r` option.